# How to get URL param with PHP websocket?

Tags: php, websocket

I created a PHP websocket server and for each client connection I need to send some URL paramaters with it.

The problem is I can't grab those $_GET parameters in the PHP websocket server script.

This is what I do in javascript to make a websocket connection, and in PHP i need the value of param, but var_dump($_REQUEST) is empty.

```
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9000/?param=1');
```

Comment: Well, it's a Websocket, not a HTTP request. You might find the params in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: True that, but got an 'undefined REQUEST_URI & QUERY_STRING'- error. I am using XAMPP btw.

Comment: Depends on your WebSocket server framework that you are using.

Comment: Nothing special, just PHP websocket extension which is included in xampp package

Comment: From what I learned, while solving the same problem, this is not possible with just PHP as a server. The next best thing I ultimately got working was immediately after connecting to send message with the param (presumably something like chatroom ID) and in the PHP script I have an array of such params for every connection. For every incoming message I check this array and send outgoing message only to corresponding clients with the same param value.